# BouncyCastle.NetCore : Impossible to find the CryptoApiRandomGenerator class

Tags: .net-core, bouncycastle

I've installed the BouncyCastle.NetCore package in order to create a self signed certificate but i couldn't found the **CryptoApiRandomGenerator**  class.

Is it normal? if yes what is the substitute?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your own CryptoApiRandomGenerator.
Something like this:

```
public class MyCryptoApiRandomGenerator
    : IRandomGenerator
{
    private readonly RNGCryptoServiceProvider rndProv;

    public NetMatchCryptoApiRandomGenerator()
    {
        rndProv = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
    }

    #region IRandomGenerator Members

    public virtual void AddSeedMaterial(byte[] seed)
    {
        // I don't care about the seed
    }

    public virtual void AddSeedMaterial(long seed)
    {
        // I don't care about the seed
    }

    public virtual void NextBytes(byte[] bytes)
    {
        rndProv.GetBytes(bytes);
    }

    public virtual void NextBytes(byte[] bytes, int start, int len)
    {
        if (start < 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("Start offset cannot be negative", "start");
        if (bytes.Length < (start + len))
            throw new ArgumentException("Byte array too small for requested offset and length");

        if (bytes.Length == len && start == 0)
        {
            NextBytes(bytes);
        }
        else
        {
            byte[] tmpBuf = new byte[len];
            rndProv.GetBytes(tmpBuf);
            Array.Copy(tmpBuf, 0, bytes, start, len);
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

There isn't an implicit implementation for this in .Net Core at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Andrei Ardel has right if you decompile CryptoApiRandomGenerator class with "reflector" or "just decompile" you find the implementation that you can add on your project :

```
public class CryptoApiRandomGenerator : IRandomGenerator
    {
        private readonly RandomNumberGenerator rndProv;

        public CryptoApiRandomGenerator() : this(new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
        {
        }

        public CryptoApiRandomGenerator(RandomNumberGenerator rng)
        {
            this.rndProv = rng;
        }

        public virtual void AddSeedMaterial(byte[] seed)
        {
        }

        public virtual void AddSeedMaterial(long seed)
        {
        }

        public virtual void NextBytes(byte[] bytes)
        {
            this.rndProv.GetBytes(bytes);
        }

        public virtual void NextBytes(byte[] bytes, int start, int len)
        {
            if (start < 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Start offset cannot be negative", "start");
            }
            if ((int)bytes.Length < start + len)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Byte array too small for requested offset and length");
            }
            if ((int)bytes.Length == len && start == 0)
            {
                this.NextBytes(bytes);
                return;
            }
            byte[] numArray = new byte[len];
            this.NextBytes(numArray);
            Array.Copy(numArray, 0, bytes, start, len);
        }
    }
```